# Passenger Core Shutdown With No Known Cause

Tags: passenger

I have an instance of Passenger (Apache/Linux) that shutdown in a way I have never observed before and I can't find anything similar online. I'm including the log entries immediately before and after the event below.

Basically the Passenger Core shut down without any error or even evidence of a SIGTERM. I'm unable to replicate this behavior and that worries me as I can't ensure it won't happen again if I can't reproduce it or determine the cause.

I have seen many reports of "Signal received. Gracefully shutting down..." followed by "Received command to shutdown gracefully." But in all cases there is a cause like "Passenger watchdog killed" or "caught SIGTERM, shutting down". In this case there is nothing, zilch, nada. The server was operating normally and then it was shutting down "gracefully".

stdout: Using `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0`

```
[passenger_native_support.so] not compiling because PASSENGER_COMPILE_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0

[passenger_native_support.so] not downloading because PASSENGER_DOWNLOAD_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0

[passenger_native_support.so] will not be used (can't compile or download)
--> Passenger will still operate normally.

[ 2017-09-19 18:04:40.9563 11820/7f675ae4d700 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:907 ]: Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 28420, application 

[ 2017-09-19 18:04:45.2712 11820/7f675ae4d700 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:907 ]: Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 29329, application 

**[ 2017-09-19 18:04:46.9925 11820/7f6754dea700 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:585 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)**

**[ 2017-09-19 18:04:46.9926 11820/7f675ae907e0 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:989 ]: Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients have disconnected...**

[ 2017-09-19 18:04:46.9927 11820/7f675ae907e0 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:907 ]: Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 14535

[ 2017-09-19 18:04:46.9929 11820/7f675ae907e0 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:907 ]: Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 31837
```

[There are a bunch more of these "Checking whether to disconnect" messages]

```
[ 2017-09-19 18:04:47.0046 11820/7f670a1fc700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ApiServer] Freed 0 spare client objects

[ 2017-09-19 18:04:47.0047 11820/7f670a1fc700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ApiServer] Shutdown finished

[ 2017-09-19 18:04:47.0048 11820/7f673cdfa700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.7] Freed 128 spare client objects

[ 2017-09-19 18:04:47.0056 11820/7f673cdfa700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.7] Shutdown finished

[ 2017-09-19 18:04:47.0081 11820/7f673f5fe700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.3] Freed 128 spare client objects

[ 2017-09-19 18:04:47.0089 11820/7f673f5fe700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.3] Shutdown finished
```

[There are a bunch more of these "Freed 128 spare" and "Shutdown finished" messages]

```
**[ 2017-09-19 18:05:01.3870 11820/7f675ae907e0 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1055 ]: Passenger core shutdown finished**

[Tue Sep 19 18:05:02 2017] [notice] child pid 11876 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

[Tue Sep 19 18:05:02 2017] [notice] child pid 11877 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

Comment: The first thing I'd so is check your system log. The kernel may have logged a reason there. Such as out of memory or something else.

Comment: This could also be due to a regression in 5.1.8, which was fixed here: https://github.com/phusion/passenger/commit/1f0b37db

Comment: Our best guess is that daemon errantly sent a shutdown signal to the Passenger Core using an incorrect PID. However, in my testing, it seems we would have seen an indication, in the form of additional log messages, in the error.log. I'll report back if and when we are able to better determine a cause.

Comment: @S.Stambaugh did you find the cause of the issue? I'm experiencing the same issue (except the segmentation fault messages in log) after an upgrade to ubuntu 18.04 (from 14.04).

Comment: @StandardNerd, unfortunately I won't be of assistance to you as we we were able to confirm that another application was at fault. That app was erroneously killing pids it had stored, long after they were valid. Occasionally, the app would kill the pid associated with the Passenger Core. I do think it would be very helpful if Passenger would log more information in cases of an unexpected shutdown because we had to stand up a considerable amount of debugging to catch this.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting PassengerPoolIdleTime to 0 (in Apache) ?

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/#passengerpoolidletime

Comment: No, we didn't do this.